# Is rust a deal breaker? Should I buy it?

Tags: honda, civic, rust, underbody

It's a 2018 Honda civic si. It has rust in certain areas. I can still return the car. Need your opinions. Appreciate the help.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The pictures of rust you have posted don't look bad at all.  I live in the rust belt and your car resembles a car driven off the new car lot after 1 year.